# Local PersistentVolumeClaim says "no volume plugin matched"

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

I recently started exploring Kubernetes and decided to try and deploy kafka to k8s. However I have a problem with creating the persistent volume. I create a storage class and a persistent volume, but the persistent volume claims stay in status pending saying "no volume plugin matched". This is the yaml files I used with the dashed lines denoting a new file. Anybody has an idea why this is happening?

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: local-storage
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
reclaimPolicy: Retain

------------------------

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: kafka-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: local-storage
  local:
    path: /mnt/disks/ssd1
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - docker-desktop


---------------------------

kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: zookeeper-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
  storageClassName: local-storage
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As MaggieO said changing ReadWriteMany to ReadWriteOnce was part of the problem. The other part was that I had to go and create the /mnt/disks/ssd1 folder on my C: drive manually and write "path: /c/mnt/disks/ssd1" instead. Something that is not present in my example, but I was trying to do anyway and might be helpful to others was that I was trying to have two PVCs for one PV which is impossible. The PV to PVC relationship is 1 to 1.

Answer (score 3):

Your Persistent Volume Claim configuration file should look like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: zookeeper-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
  storageClassName: local-storage
```

Just change [access mode](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes) from **ReadWriteMany** to **ReadWriteOnce**.

Let me know if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You have to bound Persistent-volume claim with your persistent volume.
As you have mentioned pvc storageclassName: local-storage.
try it with as storageclassName: kafka-pv   So that your pvc get bounded to pv.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However if you add volumeName to the PVCs it defeats the purpose of storageclass and provisioners. The point is that the provisioner will automatically create PVs and assign them their respective PVCs. For instance if you use azure or aws provisioner you won't have to create PVs manually. Here the PVs are created manually because we are using the no-provisioner.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it's caused by the pv storage,just increase the mount size of the pv storage.

Answer (score 0):

From our experience (under a security-hardened Kubernetes distribution called Openshift 3.11) this provisioning error happens most often when creating of PVCs is not possible due to the node having run out of PVs.

So the cluster admin needs to add some PVs and/or we need to release some other PVCs (unused but still bound to PVs).

Having requested an incorrect PVC capacity is another possible reason (when the cluster is poorly configured and accepts only a single "magic number" for capacity).